# Is it possible to config FireFox to use a specific name server?

Tags: macos, firefox, nameserver

Currently my FireFox connects to internet by SOCKS proxy via:

```
ssh -fND localhost:30000 me@192.168.x.x
```

However, the name server for `192.168.x.x` is very restrictive and blocks many hosts. Can I `about:config` FireFox to use a particular name server (e.g. `8.8.8.8`) instead of the proxy's default?

p.s. If possible, I prefer not to modify the name server at the network interface level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this option : `Network.proxy.socks_remote_dns` to [false](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.proxy.socks_remote_dns), which means that the SOCKS DNS will be ignored for your local DNS. You have only those two options, use the DNS via SOCKS, or use the DNS server configured on your local machine.